# How to install virtualbox dkms of the same version as virtualbox itself?

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

I have installed virtualbox with

```
sudo apt install virtualbox-6.1
```

then how should I install `dkms`? Neither of

```
sudo apt install virtualbox-dkms-6.1

sudo apt install virtualbox--6.1-dkms

sudo apt install virtualbox-dkms=6.1
```

worked.

If I do

```
sudo apt install virtualbox-dkms
```

it installs version 5.2

Comment: Which Ubuntu version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I was to run

```
sudo rcvboxdrv setup
```

according to here: https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch02.html#externalkernelmodules

Answer (score 0):

Extract the `virtualbox` version :

Install `grep-dctrl` : `sudo apt install grep-dctrl`

```
version=$(grep-status -sVersion -PX 'virtualbox' |awk -F: '{print $2}' | sed 's/ //')
```

Install the `virtualbox-dkms` using the extracted version:

```
sudo apt install virtualbox-dkms="$version"
```